# Fetching value of selected cell in grid view in Android

Tags: java, android

The following is my code, which entails an implementation of a grid view.

```
package com.example.dhavalpatel.atira;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class second extends ActionBarActivity 
{ 

     GridView gv;  

    String[] value1=value1=new String[]{"0","0","0","0","0"};
    String imc_met;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);



        gv=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
   ArrayAdapter<String> ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,value1);

            gv.setAdapter(ad);






}
```

**Question:**

I would like to be able to find out which cell is clicked on on my grid view and be able to retrieve the corresponding value in it from the selected cell.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use OnItemClickListener as follows

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //based on the position you have to get value
           String value=value1[position];
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE :**

Yeah you can change value of a cell that you are selected as follows

in onItemClick(-,-,-,-) of setOnItemClickListener write as follows

```
value1[position]=234;
ad.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it was a big help. Can you please help me in one more thing, can i change the selected value and change it, like as i click on cell and then change it.  As for example String value=value1[position]; if(value=="0") {  set value1[poistion]==1  };

Answer (score 0):

Try with the method `gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)` and something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long ida) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, ida);

   Cursor mycursor = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
   //and then get the values like mycursor.getString(1) for example
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind click event on gridView like as.

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```